# Cyclic Constructor Object loop java

Tags: java, loops, exception

**Firstly** its a stack over flow question i know that it has overflown because of large number of objects are created.
But the question is that I haven't stored any **object reference** in a reference initially so why ain't the garbage collector dumping when the resources are used and there's no reference to the objects.

**Secondly**
See those exceptions below Why are those **FileOutputStream.write()**  exceptions there when there isn't any file handling in code?

```
class Base{
    Base(){
        Constructorloop c=new  Constructorloop();

    }
}

class Constructorloop{
    static int i=0;
    Constructorloop(){
        System.out.println(i+++" X 2 objects created");
        Base  b=new Base();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Base();
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
        at Constructorloop.<init>(Constructorloop.java:11)
        at Base.<init>(Constructorloop.java:3)
        at Constructorloop.<init>(Constructorloop.java:12)
        at Base.<init>(Constructorloop.java:3)
        at Constructorloop.<init>(Constructorloop.java:12)
```

Comment: You've got an endless loop there.  It's blowing the stack because you're calling the base constructor which calls the derived constructor which calls the base constructor which ...

Comment: Actually 5 last lines of stack trace are the key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You observe partially correctly that a stack overflow error is caused because you are creating many objects in a loop. As for the garbage collector: it doesn't run continuously. Rather, it waits for an opportune time. You may not be saving references to the objects you're creating, but references are still placed on the stack (though the objects themselves live on the heap). What is more, calling a function repeatedly places a return reference on the stack for each call, so it may not even be the object creation which causes the stack overflow exception.

As for the exception in `FileOutputStream`: in your endless loop, `System.out.println` is called repeatedly and it uses a stream for its output. Internally, it will call methods with call other methods, all adding to your stack, until it runs out of stack space.

In summary, an endless loop of functions calling themselves will always run out of stack space, whether you're creating object instances or not.